# Matrix inverse for clustered values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have a (covariance) matrix that's been so ordered that the components can be grouped into within-group dependence and between-group independence, something like this:

$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\alpha & 1 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \beta & 0\\
0 & 0 & \beta & 1 & \beta\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \beta & 1
\end{array} \right) 
$$

Is there a formula to compute $A^{-1}$? What about an arbitrary number of these blocks with arbitrary sizes?

Comment: You can invert [block diagonal matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) block by bock.

Comment: Are $\alpha,\beta$ just constants?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yes, I'd just have a constant value for all matrix blocks. The point is that I'm partitioning a data set into variables whose errors are uniformly, highly correlated. However the block sizes might be very large.

Comment: @cgreen in that case, $A^{-1}$ would not exist

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I'm realizing this now. I'm altering the question now to fix it.

Comment: @cgreen you can invert the matrix block-by-block as Cristoph suggests.  Use [this method](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Inversion) to find the inverse of a particular block.